# C compilers default behavior with constants

Tags: c, compiler-construction, casting, type-conversion

Say I do the following:

```
char x;

x = x + 077;
```

In this situation does the constant 077 have a default type of int even though the expression is assigning to a char? From reading K&R I have inferred that the + operator has higher precedence than = and the 077 (octal) has a default type of int, thus the value of x is promoted to an int. Then the addition operation is performed and then the answer of converted back to a char and assigned to x. Is this correct?

Does the same behavior happen for the following two expressions?:

```
x += 077
x += 1
```

Also, what happens if the following is used in an expression:

```
(char) 14
```

Is 14 first an int by default which is then reduced to a char, or is it a char to begin with?

```
char x;

x = 14;
```

Also, in this case is 14 first an int which is then reduced to a char or is it a char to begin with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`14`, `1` and `077` are integer literals, and those are always `int` or some larger type, never a `char`. That type doesn't depend on the context. (See C99 §6.4.4.1 for the details on the actual type.)

The compound assignment `a += b` behave exactly as the corresponding `a = a + b` expression, except that `a` is only evaluated once:

> (C99 §6.5.16.2/3) A compound assignment of the form `E1 op = E2` differs from the simple assignment expression `E1 = E1 op (E2)` only in that the lvalue `E1` is evaluated only once.

Comment: How can `a` only be evaluated once if it is converted into an int and then back to a char as above?

Comment: Promotions and conversions aren't evaluations of `a`. (Imagine that `a` was not a variable but a function that returns a char (if that was possible in this context) - that function would only be called once with the `+=` operator. But twice with the `a=a+b` expression.)

Comment: So to clarify, what exactly is an _evaluation_ of `a`?

Comment: I think I've got it. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12133739/arithmetic-assignment-operator-left-side-evaluated-only-once