# what does "|=" operator mean in C?

Tags: c, operator-keyword

How does this code work:

```
int a = 1;
int b = 10;

a |= b;
```

how the `a |= b;` works? Seems like `|=` is not an operator in C?

Comment: It is same as : `a = a | b`;

Comment: This is an elementary question, answerable by reading any decent C book or tutorial. (Operator symbols typically appear at the beginning of the index, before 'A').

Comment: Don't downvote for no reason, please.  A simple question isn't necessarily a bad question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does the |= operator mean in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4217762/what-does-the-operator-mean-in-c)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It works like the | + the = operator, in a similar way as += works.

It is equivalent as

```
a = a|b;
```

I suggest you to read this article about operators: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B#Bitwise_operators
Ans this one about bitwise operation
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation

Answer (score 2):

Following the pattern of, for example, `+=`:

```
a |= b;
// Means the same thing as:
a = a | b;
```

That is, any bits that are set in either `a` or `b` shall be set in `a`, and those set in neither shall not be set in `a`.

Answer (score 2):

That's the "bitwise or" equal.  It follows in the pattern of the plus equal `+=`, minus equal `-=`, etc.

`a |= b;` is the same as `a = a | b;`

Comment: "Bitwise or equal" is not the name of this operator.  You are confusing it with `>=` et al., which are comparison operators.  `|=` is not a comparison operator.

Comment: The phrasing is a bit odd, so I'll edit it.  I mean "bitwise or" equal.  Kinda like "plus" equal.

Comment: Ah, yes, I see what you mean now.  The "or" does make it difficult to construct an operator name with the same pattern as plus-equal.

Answer (score 2):

The expression `a |= b;` is equivalent to the expression `a = a | b;`.

Answer (score 2):

This is compound assignment operator.
It has meaning:

```
a = a | b;
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the same as

```
a = a | b;
```

The same way as `+=` `-=` etc

Answer (score 2):

Its the [bitwise OR operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#OR), and

```
a |= b;
```

Its the same thing as

```
a = a | b;
```